# Selective amplification of a voice signal

Tags: software, signal-processing, background, selection, active-noise-control

In many TV programmes, the director is speaking to the show host via an ear-piece that the host is wearing, and at many instances, what is being said through that ear-piece is more or less audible without any processing.

How can I selectively amplify this voice from the background (what software/manuals should I follow)?

Here's an example:

in this video on times: 1:06, 1:12 and 1:18. There is a clear dictation of what is said by the host. I need to know if it is possible to clear out and amplify this signal.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Wow that is a crazy post production/forensic/restauration job. The problem is that the signal is very little. What you can do is you can use volume envelopes to increase the directors voice. So that you push the level in-between the hosts words. Then there will be an extreme amount of background noise. Sou you can use a restoration plug in like stylus rx or waves wms plugin to peace by peace filter out unnecessary background noise. Then you should also eq the sample by high passing at around 300 hz and low passing at around 7 kHz. and boosting between 2 kHz and 4 kHz. This will bring the speech a little bit forward.

All in all good luck with that.